# How to setup model binding with an Authorization Token

Tags: c#, jwt, model-binding

I am trying to create a middleware with a model binder for my C# API that automatically extract JWT claims from an Authorization bearer token and adds them to a model for easy access in the controller. I have seen similar implementations for binding request headers but cannot find information on how to do this specifically for JWT claims. Can someone provide guidance or an article on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**MAINSTREAM OPTION**

In a .NET API the simplest option is to use the standard middleware:

```cs
private void ConfigureOAuth(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = this.configuration.IssuerBaseUrl;
            options.Audience = this.configuration.Audience;
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    });
}
```

In controllers you can then access `this.User`, which is a request scoped object. It can be made injectable into other classes if can write this code at application startup:

```cs
services.AddScoped(ctx => ctx.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

**CUSTOM OPTION**

The [JwtBearerHandler class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs) doesn't make it easy to use an alternative claims object, but you can do so with a custom authentication handler. First write code similar to this at application startup:

```cs
services.AddScoped(ctx => new ClaimsHolder());
services.AddScoped(ctx => ctx.GetService<ClaimsHolder>().Claims);
```

Then write a custom authentication handler, which can override the JwtBearerHandler class or provide its own implementation:

```cs
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    var claimsJson = ...
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy(),
        },
    };

    var claims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClaimsModel>(claimsJson, settings);

    var claimsHolder = this.Context.RequestServices.GetService<ClaimsHolder>();
    claimsHolder.Claims = claims;
}
```

The holder class is a way to make a request scoped object injectable at runtime.

**EXAMPLE .NET API**

My .NET API uses some of these techniques, though my motivation was to use a particular JWT library rather than Microsoft's JWT handling, and get to know the extensibility points. A couple of relevant classes below, though in most APIs it is probably best to stick to the mainstream option.

- [JWT Validation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.cs)
- [Custom Authentication Handler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/security/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs)
- [Injected Claims](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/logic/services/CompanyService.cs)